BSD sed/awk moving portion of line to line above (switching attribute in HTML file)
My situation is simple : I have an HTML file with several lines containing only the indented <section> block tag, each line followed by an (also indented) <h3 id="YYYY">...</h3> title tag.
Like so :
    <section>
        <h3 id="2024"><a href="index.fr.html#2024">fr</a> 2024 <a href="index.html#2024">en</a></h3>

When using the anchored link to go to a specific year within the page (or its translation), the year title goes to hide behind the <header>.
The problem would be solved by switching the id attribute one line up from the <h3> to the <section> tag,
like so :
    <section id="2024">
        <h3><a href="index.fr.html#2024">fr</a> 2024 <a href="index.html#2024">en</a></h3>

Is there a simple one-liner or command that would permit me to switch all these id attributes from the <h3> tag to the <section> tag one line further up ? I have not found how to match multiple lines in BSD sed or especially awk.
sed 's:<section>\(\s*\)<h3\( id="\[0-9\]{4}"\):<section\2>\1<h3:g' index.html
does not change the file. Neither does \n\t\t in place of \s, or using double backslashes escapes.
Is there an option to match for space characters like I assume GNU sed would ? Only perhaps the insertion/use of newlines/tabs directly in the command, but I would like to learn better and am also forced since I am working remotely and have to use termux on Android ... Also I am not skilled enough to use an awk workaround.

You are seeking to use "flat text", line oriented tools to manipulate structured (HTML) text. This is unsafe. Apply a programming language (perl, python, ...) with helpful libtaries. There is a learning curve.

You can't parse (X)HTML with regex..

also consider updating the question to include a few more lines of text ... a few lines that match and do not match your <section> / <h3 id ...> requirement, also a pair of <section id ...> / <h3> lines that have already been modified

Nonsensical file with matching and non-matching lines, as well as a pair of lines that already have the correct format:
$ cat index.html
<html>
    <section>
        <h2 id="2023"><a href="index.fr.html#2023">fr</a> 2023 <a href="index.html#2023">en</a></h3>

    <section>
        <h3 id="2024"><a href="index.fr.html#2024">fr</a> 2024 <a href="index.html#2024">en</a></h3>

    <section id="2025">
        <h3><a href="index.fr.html#2025">fr</a> 2025 <a href="index.html#2025">en</a></h3>
</html>

While it may be possible to do this with sed, my sed skills are not up to the task.
While OP has stated - I am not skilled enough to use an awk workaround - the question has been tagged with awk, so I'll take a shot at an awk solution ...
awk -F'[<>]' '                                                  # split on dual delimiters "<" and ">"
$2 == "section" { line1 = $0                                    # if 2nd field is "section", save current line
                  if (getline && $2 ~ /^h3 id=/) {              # read next line and if 2nd field starts with "h3 id=" then ...
                     match($2,/id=.*$/)                         # find the "id=..." string
                     id = substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH)             # save said string
                     sub(/<section>/,"<section " id ">",line1)  # update "line1" variable
                     sub("<h3 " id ">","<h3>")                  # update current line
                  }
                  print line1                                   # print "line1"
                }
1                                                               # print current line
' index.html

This generates:
<html>
    <section>
        <h2 id="2023"><a href="index.fr.html#2023">fr</a> 2023 <a href="index.html#2023">en</a></h3>

    <section id="2024">
        <h3><a href="index.fr.html#2024">fr</a> 2024 <a href="index.html#2024">en</a></h3>

    <section id="2025">
        <h3><a href="index.fr.html#2025">fr</a> 2025 <a href="index.html#2025">en</a></h3>
</html>

